Western, where a character is buried up to his neck in desert sand, involving a snake
My girlfriend suffers from ophidiophobia and traces it back to a movie she saw on TV in her early childhood during the late 80s. The movie might be much older than that. She remembers this one scene, where a man gets buried to his neck in desert sand when a snake approaches. Her memory isn't clear, but she thinks that the movie then implies, that he bites the snakes head off.
Does this sound familiar? Which movie is this scene from?

Are you sure that it is a snake that approaches?

There is a similar scene in The Ballad of Cable Hogue

Yes, there are several movies with scenes that include a person being buried up to their neck in the sand; however, I recall other types of "creatures" other than snakes in each one.

Sorry for my delayed answer. Found the StackExchange notification in my spam folder today.

Sorry for my delayed answer. I found the StackExchange notification in my spam folder today. She is still pretty sure that it was a snake, yet it's possible her memories are mingled with other movies. The so called "sand necktie" is a common trope as mentioned here: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SandNecktie

How about "The Secret of the Sahara":

an Italian TV Miniseries directed by Alberto Negrin and broadcast in 1987 in seven episodes of approximately 52 minutes each.

Snake scene at 6:50:




That's it! Interesting, how she assumed it was a western, seeing a dirty stubble bearded man in a desert with a rattle snake. Here it was called "Das Geheimnis der Sahara" and the biting scene was cut, due to it airing in the afternoon.
